# Subclass attribute in Subclass of superclass attribute in Superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, subclass, decoupling

I have a problem creating two classes that share heavy amount of code, with an attribute of the subclass meant to be a subclass of the attribute in the superclass. Let me provide a dummy example of what the root of the problem is:

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A{
}

public class X{
 A value;
}
public class Y extends X{
 B value;
}
```

The shared code makes use of either A or B, depending on the situation. Converting value to protected and ignoring the problem did not work, during runtime in debugging of operations of class B, while in a shared method, I could see that Y.value was filled but X.value was not, eventually raising a NullPointerException.
To face that issue I thought about adding a generic type T to the design thus:

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A{
}

public class X<T extends A>{
 T value;
}
public class Y extends X<B>{
}
```

which seems to work. Unfortunately however, there is a part of the code that tries to initialize the A or B, with a default constructor, which forces me to increase the complexity of the code with commands, like try catch handlders, that would otherwise not be needed. Another way of solving this situation was by introducing a parent class P:

```
public class A {


public class B extends A{
}

/**The abstract class has abstract the method that creates the T object
*/
public abstract class P<T extends A> {

}

public class X extends P<A>{
}
public class Y extends P<B>{
}
```

or creating an interface in the position of P, which would cause the requirement of the creation of a lot static methods that would need to be explicitly called in the implenting classes

Conclusively, I would like to ask whether there is a better solution than the ones I suggested, or which one of the above patterns seems the best to follow. FYI, I come from a Python background, where I had not faced such situations due to , well, duck typing.

**EDIT**
The reason why I am presenting this problem is that A and X are classes residing in one package and B and Y are classes residing in another, thus all of them are needed, but the operations that differ need to be self-contained. A use case would be two extensions to a program, one extension depending on the code of another extension to work. The extensions are supposed to solve different parts of the same problem, but the super-extension is not supposed to have cross dependency with the inheriting one.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need class Y? Using generics, you can use class X either with a type of A either with a type of B.

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class X<T extends A> {
    
    private final T value;

    public X(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    X<B> xb = new X<>(b);
    X<A> xa = new X<>(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing the lack of context, I updated the description